# Vue 3: Why dom ref value is undefined when ref in Vue 3 template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am using Vue 3 beta version and I am trying to access ref in setup function, My component:

JS(Vue):

```js
const Child = createComponent({
  setup () {
    let tabs = ref()
    console.log(tabs)
    return {}
  },
  template: '<div ref="tabs" >Wow</div>'
})
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xkeyLwu4/2/

But the value of tabs.value is undefined. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. You need to have `setup()` return a ref with the same name.
2. You can't log the DOM result until after mounting (`onMounted`)

```js
const Child = createComponent({
  setup () {
    let tabs = ref()
    onMounted(() => console.log(tabs.value))
    return { tabs }
  },
  template: '<div ref="tabs" >Wow</div>'
})
```

See the docs for more examples: https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#template-refs

Comment: One question, Will this work if I use this in a function that is inside setup function?

Comment: @Ilyaskarim as long as that function is called after mounting, it should be fine. Feel free to post a new question if you run into problems

Comment: Am I the only one who really dislikes that you are forced to use the ref name for the variable name? I think there should be a better solution for refs on DOM elements.

Comment: Does this approach with a setup()-function work with class-based TS-components, too?

Comment: @Sth I am not very familiar with TS, looks like you need to call a `defineComponent` wrapper function. Might be worth a new question. Here's some info tho: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#defining-vue-components

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass a value to ref in order to initialize it:

```js
let tabs = ref([tab1, tab2, ...])

console.log(tabs) // tabs.value is now [tab1, tab2, ...]
```

Comment: I am trying to access from the template. Please see https://jsfiddle.net/xkeyLwu4/2/. The value of tabs is undefined, It should be a DOM element.

Comment: You are confusing refs for Vue 3 and ref to dom elements. They are completely different concepts

Comment: in the setup function you can't access the dom elements, because the template is not renderend yet (you are __setting up__ the data used to render the template)