# Trying to replace getElementByID with refs in vue 3 won't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js

### What I'm Trying to do

I am new to Vue and I'm trying to replace `getElementByID` with `$refs`, but I get the following error:

### Errors

[image: Console Errors]

### Code

Here is the HTML:

```html
<router-link to="/" ref="navOpt">
    <div ref="activeOpt">
```

Here is the script:

```js
// imports
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";

// setup
setup() {
  let navOpt = ref();
  let activeOpt = ref();
  onMounted(() => this.$refs.navOpt);
  onMounted(() => this.$refs.activeOpt);
  return { navOpt, activeOpt };
},

// Methods - check if the navOpt is active and removes css if it is
checkActiveRoute() {
  if (this.navOpt.classList.contains("router-link-active")) {
    this.activeOpt.classList.remove("hide-active");
  }
},

// Created - call method on load
created() {
  this.checkActiveRoute();
},
```

### Tried Solutions

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63268627/vue-3-why-dom-ref-value-is-undefined-when-ref-in-vue-3-template) but it gave me the same error.

Can someone help with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ref` values are automatically bound to the `ref` attribute in your elements, and there's no need to do `onMounted(() => this.$refs.navOpt)` since this doesn't have any effect, you should also use only one API (composition or options), but it's recommended to use the composition API, finally define the method just a function which should be called in the onMounted hook :

```html
setup() {
  let navOpt = ref();
  let activeOpt = ref();
  onMounted(() => {
     checkActiveRoute()
   });

function checkActiveRoute() {
  if (navOpt.value.classList.contains("router-link-active")) {
        activeOpt.value.classList.remove("hide-active");
  }
}
  return { navOpt, activeOpt };
},
```